# Updating a public Outlook calendar from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I need to update an Outlook calendar when the user clicks the button to run. It will take the appointments start date, end date, subject, and body then save the appointment. I have full access to this public folder and am able to create appointments manually, but it does not seem to work through the code.

Note: the code as-is is not causing any debug errors but just doesn't complete the intended task when it runs. It will finish then I will check the calendar and the appointment won't be there.

```vb
Sub UpdateOutlookCalendar()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNamespace As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olAppointment As Object
    

    
    ' Create a new Outlook application instance
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Get the Outlook namespace
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    

    ' Open the shared calendar folder (change "Shared Calendar" to the actual folder name)
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("Payroll")
    
    ' Loop through the Excel range and create appointments in Outlook


    
    Set olAppointment = olFolder.Items.Add
        olAppointment.Start = "09/05/2023 09:00 AM"
        olAppointment.End = "09/05/2023 10:00 AM"
        olAppointment.Subject = "Test"
        olAppointment.Body = "No fab"
        olAppointment.Save

    
    ' Clean up
    Set olAppointment = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
    ' Notify the user that the operation is complete
    MsgBox "Calendar update complete.", vbInformation
End Sub
```